# Impossible to get messages details in a list request with Gmail API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-client

I am using a ruby on rails app which connects to the Gmail API. When I make a `list`request to get all the messages of one mailbox, I only get back an `id`and a `threadId` property for each message.

I tried to follow [Gmail API Doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance?hl=fr#partial) using the `fields` parameters to get other properties (title, date...). It doesn't work, whether I use the `google-api-client` gem in my app, or by doing a direct `GET` request.

Adding any other parameters to the request ends with a failure. Here is the url that works :
`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?fields=messages(id,threadId)`

Am I forced to make one call per message or using batch requests to get relevant datas ? It seems a little heavy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to [**list messages**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) like you've done, and then [**get each message in a separate request**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get).

**Request 1**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=1&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response 1**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "15fd9f0fe242f975",
   "threadId": "15fd9f0fe242f975"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "11889180580605610074",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 2
}
```

**Request 2**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/15fd9f0fe242f975?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response 2**

```
{
 "id": "15fd9f0fe242f975",
 "threadId": "15fd9f0fe242f975",
 "labelIds": [
  "IMPORTANT",
  "CATEGORY_UPDATES",
  "INBOX"
 ],
 "snippet": "Tasks tracked last week...",
 "historyId": "966691",
 ...
}
```

It's also possible to get the total amount of request down from `1 + n of messages` to 2 by using [**batch requests**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch).

Comment: Also:  if you're getting more than a few messages, you'll need batch requests for any sensible performance, BUT, each request in the batch is counted toward rate limits so you may need to pace your batches.  Also-also, non-draft messages are immutable (generally, except for deletion and labels) so a client should only have to get message details exactly once.

Comment: There must be some Ruby gem that abstracts this, no? What an annoying situation! Am I wrong?

Comment: @TomLehman I know barely anything about the Ruby ecosystem, but there is an [official Ruby Quickstart in the documentation for the Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby).